# MySql - multithread software, how to lock row to prevent reading by other thread

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading

I have a table of users in **MySql**

**Structure:**

ID - big int
Text - Varchar
Verified = false (by default)
Thread = false by default / set true when thread works with current row.

**WorkFlow**

1. Get row by our condition
2. Set thread true to prevent other thread work with them
3. Do magic
4. Set verified true
5. Set thread false

Problem is when I have 5 or more threads. Before step 2 ends, other thread gets the same row. From 90 threads, up to 40% can work at the same row. Adding random timing before request did not help too much.

**My question is:** How to temporary lock the row, to prevent reading by other thread?

Comment: Use a `transaction`: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-transaction.aspx

Comment: Don't handle that from the application use MySQL to handle this.. MySQL 5.5+ and InnoDB engine has connection session based row locks.. read ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html )

Comment: This isn't anything special about multithreading.  Databases can be accessed concurrently by any number of clients - it's not just your own application's threads you have to worry about, it's every other client connected to the database.  Like @Aaron suggests, a transaction allows you to bundle a series of database operations into a coherent atomic operation, including the option of using rollbacks to undo the operation cleanly if it should fail or need to be withdrawn.

Comment: As well as a transaction you should also use a FOR UPDATE lock on the select to prevent deadlocks. So the select will put a write lock on the row, preventing other threads from locking the same row; the other threads will wait for the row to be unlocked at the end of the transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply exclusive locks on InnoDB records:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 666 FOR UPDATE;
```

Thus other user/thread can't read these records you locked.

Since the locks will be released automatically when the transaction finished. So you usually need to start a transaction by `START TRANSACTION` or `BEGIN`, and put the statement above in this transaction.

Comment: Thank you. It's work perfectly. But only with 30 thread, on 40 threads and more I have got Timeout due to completion other operations. I set up global read/write timeout to 9999 but it not helps.

Comment: It's a pleasure.